# Selecting every other block of elements from MATLAB array

Tags: arrays, matlab

We all know how to select every other n element using index like A[1:n:end]. Suppose I have a 1000x1 array and I divide (conceptually) it into blocks of 5 elements, and I want to select every other block, i.e., to select A[1], A[2], A[3], A[4], A[5] and A[11], A[12], A[13], A[14], A[15], ..., you got the idea.

Of course I can generate an index array beforehand and use it, but I am wondering if there are more convenient ways.

Comment: Please use MATLAB syntax for a MATLAB question. You cannot index an array using `[]` in MATLAB. If you can do it by generating an index array beforehand then I highly suggest you add that code to your question because it (a) shows us that you've made some effort and are not just asking for someone else to write code for you (b) it explains what you are actually trying to do as it is current quite ambiguous and (c) it stops someone else wasting their time posting that exact same solution.

Answer (score 0):

So in effect you are trying to create a square wave indexing function, how about something like

```
n = 1:numel(A); %// assuming A is a vector (i.e. 1D)
w = 2^-3;
idx = sin(2*pi*w*n) > 0;
```

You then tune `w` to change block width.

Alternatively

```
w = 3
idx = floor(mod(0:n-1),2*w)/w);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reshape the array into a matrix:

```
A = rand(1000,1);
n = 5;
B = reshape(A,n,[]);
```

Now each column of `B` is a group:

```
B(:,1) == A(1:5)
B(:,2) == A(6:10)
...
```

From there you can select every other column of B the same way you would for a vector:

```
B = B(:,1:2:end);
```